# Creating a D3D9 Hardware Overlay Issue

Tags: c++, overlay, direct3d

I want to overlay and D3D game using a D3D hardware overlay. I'm creating the overlay with this function: ([source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd797814%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))

```
HRESULT CreateHWOverlay(HWND hwnd, IDirect3D9Ex *pD3D, IDirect3DDevice9Ex **ppDevice)
{
    *ppDevice = NULL;

    D3DCAPS9                caps;
    ZeroMemory(&caps, sizeof(caps));

    HRESULT hr = pD3D->GetDeviceCaps(
        D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT,
        D3DDEVTYPE_HAL,
        &caps
        );

    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        return hr;
    }

    // Check if overlay is supported.
    if (!(caps.Caps & D3DCAPS_OVERLAY))
    {
        return D3DERR_UNSUPPORTEDOVERLAY;
    }

    D3DOVERLAYCAPS          overlayCaps = { 0 };

    IDirect3DDevice9Ex           *pDevice = NULL;
    IDirect3D9ExOverlayExtension *pOverlay = NULL;

    // Check specific overlay capabilities.
    hr = pD3D->QueryInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&pOverlay));

    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = pOverlay->CheckDeviceOverlayType(
            D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT,
            D3DDEVTYPE_HAL,
            1920,
            1200,
            D3DFMT_X8R8G8B8,
            NULL,
            D3DDISPLAYROTATION_IDENTITY,
            &overlayCaps
            );
    }

    // Create the overlay.
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {

        DWORD flags =   D3DCREATE_FPU_PRESERVE | 
                        D3DCREATE_MULTITHREADED | 
                        D3DCREATE_SOFTWARE_VERTEXPROCESSING;


        D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS   pp = { 0 };

        pp.BackBufferWidth = 1920;//overlayCaps.MaxOverlayDisplayWidth;
        pp.BackBufferHeight = 1200;//overlayCaps.MaxOverlayDisplayHeight;
        pp.BackBufferFormat = D3DFMT_X8R8G8B8;
        pp.SwapEffect = D3DSWAPEFFECT_OVERLAY;
        pp.hDeviceWindow = hwnd;
        pp.Windowed = TRUE;
        pp.Flags = D3DPRESENTFLAG_VIDEO;
        pp.FullScreen_RefreshRateInHz = D3DPRESENT_RATE_DEFAULT;
        pp.PresentationInterval       = D3DPRESENT_INTERVAL_ONE;

            hr = pD3D->CreateDeviceEx(D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT, D3DDEVTYPE_HAL,
            NULL, flags, &pp, NULL, &pDevice);
    }

    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        (*ppDevice) = pDevice;
        (*ppDevice)->AddRef();
    }

    SafeRelease(&pD3D);
    SafeRelease(&pDevice);
    SafeRelease(&pOverlay);
    return hr;
}
```

painting here:

```
while(true)
{
    //Sleep(10);
    D3DRECT rect = {50,50,200,200};

    g_pDeviceEx->BeginScene();

    RECT r = {0,0,1920,1200};
    RECT xrect = {200, 200, 500, 300};

    g_Font->DrawTextA(0, "D3D HARDWARE OVERLAY", -1, &xrect, DT_LEFT, D3DCOLOR_ARGB(255,255,0,0));
    g_pDeviceEx->Clear(1, &rect, D3DCLEAR_TARGET, D3DCOLOR_ARGB(255, 0,255,0), 50.0,0);

    g_pDeviceEx->EndScene();
    g_pDeviceEx->PresentEx(&r, &r, hWnd, NULL, 0);
}
```

The overlay is just being displayed when i change the game's resolution when its black. as soon as you can see the world the text and the rect is gone. What am i doing wrong? and yes, im running windowed mode.

Answer (score 3):

The post is 2 month old but the answer is :

g_pDeviceEx->Clear -> erase backbuffer with color (255, 0,255,0), put clear before BeginScene

a+

Comment: We welcome answers to old questions; thank you for yours. However, I suggest improving the formatting somewhat (look in particular at the "code" button above the edit box, its the one with the {} on it). I'd do it for you, but I'm not entirely sure which parts of your answer are code, and which aren't.